# How to search for a string in a file using Ansible when condition

Tags: search, ansible, full-text-search, string-matching, case-when

I have a list of search string separated by '\n' in a variable `listofips`

I wish to search for the string in a file `hello.csv` which is under my `playbook_dir`

I may be having some syntax issue which I'm not sure but below is what I tried.

```
- set_fact:
    listofips: '10.0.0.1\n10.0.0.2\n10.0.0.3'

- set_fact:
    foundips: "{{ foundips + item + ', ' }}"
  when: lookup('file', "{{ playbook_dir }}/hello.csv").splitlines() | select('match', "{{ item }}") | list
  loop: "{{ listofips.split('\n') }}"
```

Unfortunately, the search string exists in the file but ansible when condition fails to match.

I would also know if it is possible to have both the `exact match` or a `wild card` match?

Can you please suggest ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a couple of issues to check:

a. foundips: "{{ foundips + item + ', ' }}"

in the first run where the condition will be true, the `foundips` is not initialized, and will error. you should use:

```
foundips: "{{ foundips|default([]) + [item] }}"
```

b. the `select` filter should use this pattern for search:

```
select('match', '.*' + item + '.*')
```

c. the `when` condition is not properly set. you convert to a list but then to make sure you have results you need to check if the list has length > 0:

```
when: lookup('file', "{{ playbook_dir }}/hello.csv").splitlines() | select('match', '.*' + item + '.*') | list | length > 0
```

d. if you use a simple debug task to see if the `split('\n')` works as expected you will realise its not, you need to use `double` backward slash:

```
loop: "{{ listofips.split('\\n') }}"
```

---

to summarize, please try this task:

```
  - set_fact:
      foundips: "{{ foundips|default([]) + [item] }}"
    when: lookup('file', "{{ playbook_dir }}/hello.csv").splitlines() | select('match', '.*' + item + '.*') | list | length > 0
    loop: "{{ listofips.split('\\n') }}"
```

cheers

Comment: Need suggestion for`exact match` @ilias-sp

Comment: hey @Ashar, you mean match a line that is equal to one of the ips? then you should use: `select('match', item)`.